# I am trying to create an Array that should request user to enter the number of rows and columns

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create an Array that should request the user to enter the number of rows and columns. My code is below, it returns no error, but when I run it, there is no prompt to enter the number of rows or columns

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserDefinedArraySize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create Scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        
                
        //Define the rows and columns Variable
        int rows = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of rows: " + rows);
        int columns = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter number of Columns: " + columns);
        
        //Define the Array
        int [][] matrix = new int [rows][columns];
```

Comment: That is because your console is waiting for user input (on the `input.nextInt()`). See what happens when you put the print statement before this line or when you enter the number of rows into your console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the prints before inputs

```
System.out.println("Enter number of rows: ");
int rows = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter number of Columns: ");
int columns = input.nextInt(); 
System.out.printf("Rows: %s, Columns: %s", rows, columns);
```

Your program was already waiting for an input and didn't get to printing out anything.

Comment: @Wowse mark it as the correct answer  then please (green checkmark), so that the question doesn't stay unanswered. Thanks!